# Does Basic4Android support named parameters like Visual Basic?

Tags: named-parameters, basic4android

Since Basic4Android is based on Visual Basic, can it support named parameters to make the code more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't.

Just for info: Basic4Android (or all of the B4X IDEs and languages) are not based on VB they are just very similar but in detail there are many differences.